# Setting domain name spring boot href

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, nginx, tomcat

I am running a spring boot war api endpoint in the cloud, however when I use the linkTo method for returning hrefs of the object, I keep getting "http://localhost:8002/api/xxx" instead of my custom domain "http://example.com/api/xxx" .

I am using a Nginx reverse proxy and run the .war file on port 8002 since 8080 is already used by another process, here is my nginx config:

```
location  /api {
         proxy_pass http://localhost:8002/api;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    }
```

How can I set my custom domain instead of the localhost?

Comment: Try to set Host or X-Forwarded-Host header

Comment: I have added  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
However it still doesn't work, do I have to add something to the application.property file ?

Comment: `server.forward-headers-strategy=native`

Maybe this will help

Comment: In fact, the Host header should solve the problem without using X-Forwarded-Host header